# Rider Ide: Jump to Method (When interface has change one argument)

Tags: c#, ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

How can I get (JetBrains) **Rider** to jump to a method, after I change something in a method's interface?

In VSCode the "Normal" "jump to" method will work, when you change the interface,
(aka the method don't fulfill the interface any more, but it's still the only overload, which is also to one that needs to be fixed to match the changes in the interface..)

Isn't there a way to enable same behavisor in Rider as in VSCode?

(Instead of having to browse to the implementation file and find the original implemed method)

Comment: Instead of manually editing the interface method, you could use the change signature refactoring (Ctrl R, S) to automatically change the signature of all implementing methods at the same time.  That way navigation will be preserved.